# activerecord default id column issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'd like to use default active record id column in the entity. For some reason the ROR engine is sending string value for that column. Any idea why that happens? It is expected that the id is ignored when inserting new data.

model:

```
class SampleModel < ApplicationRecord
end
```

this is how the ApplicationRecord looks like:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Helpers::Model

  self.abstract_class = true

  class IdType < ActiveRecord::Type::Value
    def cast(value)
      value.class == BSON::ObjectId ? value.to_s : value
    end

    def serialize(value)
      value.to_s if value
    end
  end

  attribute :id, IdType.new
  attribute :account_id, IdType.new
  attribute :affiliated_account_id, IdType.new
  attribute :content_order_id, IdType.new
  attribute :project_id, IdType.new

  class << self
    def group_by_id
      all.group_by(&:id).transform_values(&:first)
    end
  end
end
```

below is helpers module which is included into the ApplicationRecord:

```
  module Helpers
    module Model
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern
      W_AUTO_ATTRIBUTES = %w[id _id _type type created_at updated_at deleted_at version_1_id]
    end
  end

Mongoid::Document.send(:include, Wordapp::Helpers::Model)
Mongoid::Document.send(:include, Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic)
```

migration look like the following:

```
class CreateSampleModels < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :sample_models do |t|
      t.string :title, null: false
      t.string :description, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE public.sample_models
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('sample_models_id_seq'::regclass),
    title character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    description character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT sample_models_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

error when creating:

```
SampleModel.create(title: 'sample', description: 'sample')


PG::InvalidTextRepresentation - ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bigint: "60d33fc29dc7938a6a355d63"

SampleModel Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "sample_models" ("id", "title", "description", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["id", "60d33fc29dc7938a6a355d63"], ["title", "test"], ["description", "test"], ["created_at", "2021-06-23 14:05:54.192075"], ["updated_at", "2021-06-23 14:05:54.192075"]]
```

see Gemfile below. The gemfile is provided because it's possible that some gem is causing troubles:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '5.2.3'
# gem 'attr_reader :attr_namesack-timeout'
gem 'rack-cors', require: 'rack/cors'

#i18n
gem 'i18n-tasks', '~> 0.9.20'
gem 'rails-i18n', '5.0.0'
gem 'i18n-js', '~> 3.0.0.rc11'
gem 'twitter_cldr', '4.4.2', require: true

# Monitoring
gem 'rollbar', '~> 2.13.2'

gem 'yomu', '~> 0.1.5'

# DB
gem 'pg'
gem 'pg_search'
gem 'ransack', '~> 2.1.1'
gem 'mongoid', '6.2.0'
gem 'paranoia', '2.4.1'
gem 'mongoid_paranoia', github: 'simi/mongoid_paranoia', branch: 'b00af0eae33cc12443ec83f2d43d6da430353006'
gem 'has_scope', '~> 0.5.1'
gem 'simple_enum', '~> 2.1.1', require: 'simple_enum/mongoid'
gem 'redis-rails'

# Auth
gem 'doorkeeper', '~> 4.0'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.4.0'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 5.0.0'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', '~> 0.5.3'

# Backend
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'kaminari', '~> 1.1.1'
gem 'kaminari-mongoid', '~> 1.0.1'
gem 'money-rails', '~> 1.9.0'
gem 'email_validator', '~> 1.4.0'
gem 'apipie-rails', '0.5.4'
gem 'reverse_markdown', '1.0.3'
gem 'valvat', github: 'yolk/valvat', tag: 'v0.7.4'
gem 'stripe', '4.21.3'

# HTTP client utils
gem 'faraday', '~> 0.12'
gem 'typhoeus', '~> 0.7.1'

# IDN punnycode to unicode conversion
# depricated. use Addressable::IDNA.to_unicode() instead
# gem 'simpleidn', '~> 0.0.7'

# Cron Manager
gem 'clockwork', '1.2.0'
gem 'daemons'

# File uploading
gem 'carrierwave-mongoid' , '~> 0.10.0', require: 'carrierwave/mongoid'

# AWS
gem 'carrierwave-aws', '~> 1.0.2'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.5.6'

# Sidekiq
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 4.0.1'
gem 'sidekiq-delay', '~> 1.0.5'
gem 'sidekiq-status', '~> 1.0.1'
gem 'sinatra', '~> 2.0.0.beta2', require: nil
# gem 'devise-async', '~> 0.10.2'

# File import/export utilites
gem 'pandoc-ruby', '~> 0.7.5', require: 'pandoc-ruby'
gem 'wicked_pdf', '~> 1.1.0'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'

# Copyscape
gem 'copyscape', github: 'zeitnot/copyscape-rb'

# Frontend
gem 'maruku', '~> 0.7.2'
gem 'haml', '5.0.4'
gem 'haml-rails', '~> 1.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1.1'
#gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.5.0'
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '~> 4.7.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 5.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.2.1'
gem 'bower-rails', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'angular-rails-templates', '~> 1.0.2'

# Image util
gem 'fastimage', '~> 1.8.1'

gem 'faker', '~> 1.4.3', require: false, group: [:staging,:development, :test, :beta]

gem 'mandrill-api'

# for table prints (alpay added)
gem 'table_print'
gem 'hirb'
gem 'awesome_print'

# Servers
gem 'rack', '2.0.1'
gem 'puma', '3.12.1'

gem 'rubyzip', '1.2.1', require: false

# Google API
gem 'googleauth', '~> 0.6.2'
gem 'google-cloud-translate'
gem 'google-adwords-api', '~> 1.3.1'
# gem 'google-ads-googleads'
gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.8'
gem 'google_drive'
gem 'hotwater', require: false

group :production, :staging, :beta do
  gem 'asset_sync', '~> 1.0.0'
end

group :development do
  gem 'annotate'
  #gem 'guard-bundler', '~> 2.1.0'
  gem 'guard-rake', '~> 1.0.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '~> 4.6.4'
#  gem 'guard-brakeman', '~> 0.8.1'
  gem 'guard-pow', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'guard-rubocop', '~> 1.0.2'
  gem 'guard-teaspoon', '~> 0.8.0'

  gem 'better_errors', branch: 'master', github: 'charliesome/better_errors'
  gem 'rubocop', '~> 0.26.1', require: true
  gem 'brakeman', '~> 4.1.1', require: false
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'binding_of_caller', '0.8.0'

  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.7.0',           require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.2',     require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rvm', '~> 0.1.1',       require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1.3',   require: false
  gem 'capistrano-sidekiq', '~> 0.5.4',   require: false
  gem 'capistrano-maintenance', '~> 1.0', require: false
  gem 'capistrano3-puma', '3.1.1',        require: false

  gem 'yard',           require: false
  gem 'redcarpet',      require: false
  gem 'github-markup',  require: false

  gem 'bullet', '~> 5.7.2'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-rails', '~> 0.3.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.7.0'
  gem 'teaspoon-mocha', '~> 2.3.3'
  gem 'colorize'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'benchmark-ips'
end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.8'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'mongoid-rspec', github: 'zeitnot/mongoid-rspec'
  gem 'rainbow', '2.2.2' # TODO: This is here owing the codeship's failing tests.
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 2.6.1'
  gem 'json_spec', '~> 1.1.4'
  gem 'api_matchers', '~> 0.6.2'
  gem 'airborne', '~> 0.2.13'
  gem 'simplecov', '~> 0.15.0', require: false
  gem 'simplecov-console', '~> 0.4', require: false
  gem 'email_spec', '~> 1.6.0'
  gem 'rspec-sidekiq', '~> 1.0.0'
  gem 'rspec-collection_matchers', '~> 1.1.2'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.15.1'
  gem 'poltergeist', '~> 1.16.0'
  gem 'webmock', '~> 3.4.2'
  gem 'vcr', '5.0.0'
end
```

Comment: Can you run `rails db` to connect to a postgres console and then run `SELECT  nextval('sample_models_id_seq'::regclass);`?

Comment: @max when I run it - the returned value is correct integer number. 1, 2, 3...

Comment: it seems like a global configuration somewhere in the project, I just don't know where it is configured.

Comment: Ok, that tells us that the schema is not to blame. Is there anything in `ApplicationRecord` that could explain it? Do you have any gems that could be behind it? It looks suspiciously like a UUID.

Comment: There is no configuration in Rails itself AFAIK that changes the type of all the primary keys and this looks like the "wrong way" of doing UUIDS where you have the model generate defaults instead of having the DB generate it. I suspect some gem thats doing monkeypatching but can't think of any from the top of my head.

Comment: @max there are different gems installed. It's possible that some gem is causing this problem, but I don't know which one. There are two databases used mongodb and posgresql

Comment: There shouldn't really be any conflict between ActiveRecord and Mongoid unless you actually included `Mongoid::Document` in a `ActiveRecord::Base` derived model. The two can coexist - but not in the same model. Can you add the Gemfile to the question?

Answer (score 1):

You have the gems `pg` (for postgres) and some other gems for Mongoid

Is your ApplicationRecord including

```
include Mongoid::Document
include Mongoid::Ids
```

because it looks to me that ActiveRecord is using postgres as the adapter but that the generated ids come from some magic included by Mongoid::Document or Mongoid::Ids

Comment: somehow I didn't notice that the model inherits from the ApplicationRecord instead of ActiveRecord:Base. The ApplicationRecord has some id configuration. I have updated the question.

Comment: You are including mongodb stuff into a model that uses postgres. Where do you want to persist that model? Can you check the inheriting class of another model that is storing the things in the same database?